# Pebble Watch: Send notification to wake up iPhone (Watch -> Phone)

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, pebble-watch

**SITUATION:** None of iPhone's physical buttons (except volume) are operational. Thus, can virtually only activate screen by receiving a notification.

Instead of simply getting the buttons repaired, I want to see if it can be an opportunity to learn.

**PROJECT:** Make a simple Pebble app in Cloud Pebble that will **send an (arbitrary) basic notification to my iPhone**, waking it up. That way, I can activate the screen remotely by, for example, clicking the Pebble middle 'Select' button. [SMS may do, but seems to be a long route compared to Bluetooth communication.]

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make an app that will use the Twilio API to send yourself an SMS. You could also use one of the services that sends you push notifications.

Comment: Specifically, IFTTT makes it easy to send push notifications via their API.